# Replace all commas and square brackets using Regex Expression

Tags: javascript, regex

Hope u people will be fine. I want to print a array variable in javascript, but the problem is that when i print the array a comma seperated list is shown. But i do not want commas between each array value. **Is there any method to print array variable wihtout commas?**

If not, Please tell me what is the **regex expression** to replace all occurence of '],['(wihtout quotes) with ']['.

Waiting for ur kind replies.

Regards

Answer (score 3):

You can use regex, but the most obvious way is to just `join` the array, IMO:

```
var arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
alert(arr.join("")); // alerts "abcd"
```

Note that `join` is flexible in that you could change the delimiter above with something like `arr.join("-")`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are seeing '],[' then you may have arrays as content of the array (i.e. a multi-dimentional array) and have tried *Array.prototype.join*. e.g.

```
var x = [[1,2],[3,4]];
alert(x);  // 1,2,3,4
alert(x.join(''));  // 1,23,4
```

Simply using the Array's built-in *toString* method with an regular expression may do the job:

```
var re = /,/g;
alert(x.toString().replace(re, ''));  // 1234
```

However a better method (i.e. applicable to a wider variety of cases) might be to iterate over the contents of the array and deal with values that are also arrays.

Comment: its not multi-dimentional array, its an array containing wordpress shorcodes, However join() method works here too. Thank u for answer.